# Can I test Debian from its live USB being with Windows installed on my machine?

Tags: debian, windows, dual-boot, live-usb

For example, I can run test Ubuntu from USB. They explicitly say in their tutorials that I can do it, that the Windows may be installed on my machine but I safely for my Windows can run and see and basically test Ubuntu from USB.

I'm reading now about Debian live USB. But there is no any word if it is possible to run Debian from USB the same way as Ubuntu on machine with Windows XP installed. It it as safe as Ubuntu? Or is it possible only if some Linux is installed on my machine, not Windows?

I don't want to install it for now. I just want to run it to see it. I don't want it to damage my current Windows XP.

Answer (score 4):

You can use any flavor of linux from a liveUSB, none will require the presence of a linux install on your machine. That's one of the main purposes of a liveCD/liveUSB, to be able to try/use a distro from an external medium, regardless of the OS that is actually installed on that machine. As long as you don't start any install setup, it will not touch your drives/existing setup.